# android ToggleButton Exception raised during rendering: -1

Tags: android, togglebutton

I created a simple app for android but I always when I add ToggleButton in the xml file and go to the graphical layout I get this error message:

Exception raised during rendering: -1
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogThe graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:
Different corner sizes are not supported in Path.addRoundRect. (Ignore for this session)

here is my code:

```
<ToggleButton 
android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textOn="Vibrate on"
android:textOff="Vibrate off"
android:onClick="onToggleClicked"/>
```

Comment: @user2749139 Run the code, see if it renders on the device anyway. From what I have seen, the Android Studio design editor has a lot of issues. You can also try changing the device it is rendering with (on top of the editor), but that doesn't always work.

Comment: @Bryan I am using eclipse and when I run the app in my phone it works, but I cant see the graphical layout and got the error.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was saying, sometimes it will not show up in the graphical layout, but it will render correctly on an emulator/device. I see you got it working by changing the device, which will work sometimes, but not all the time. I tend to not use the graphical editor much because of this.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it, all I had to do is changing the target of the graphical layout like this:

[image]